# hover not working with a background image

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image

I have a website with a background image but when I add a css navigation  bar the hover tag doesn't work. the hover element works with out the back ground image but when i add the background image it dosent

here's my code

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cool</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" "type= "text/css" rel= "stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon2.jpg"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background-image">
    <div id="background-overlay">
    <h1>Cool</h1>
            <h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>

            <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
z-index:-8;
}
body{
margin:0px;
}
#backround-image{
background-image:url("background.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
position:relative;
top: 0;
bottom :0;
height: 100vh;
z-index: -10;
}
#backround-overlay{
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index:-9;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
font-family:arial black;


}
l{
float:left;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover{
background-color: red;
color: black;
}
```

thanks for any help

Thomas

Comment: You have an extra `"` before `type` in your CSS inclusion. This may be throwing a syntax error that causes your CSS not to load. Also you have an `l` selector in your CSS (where you float to the left), which is likely meant to be `li`.

Comment: ^While true, that is not his issue. In codepen I am able repro the problem.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is what you're looking for but I just put the background image on the body and it seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/szoevqaL/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove position: relative; from background-image the issue is resolved and doesn't cause any weirdness. At the moment this appears to be unnecessary styling.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like hovering doesn't work on element background if the element already had a background before. However, if you want to change the element's background you can do it with changing it's brightness, hue, saturation. Here is an example:

```
          li a:hover {
             filter: brightness(50%);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easyest way:

```
`background-blend-mode: color-burn;`
```